# Is there a way I can add comment and uncomment to options to right click menu is Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the code editor panel in VS Code, I would like an 'comment line' and 'uncomment line' option to be available when i right click. Is this possible or is there an extension to do this? I've searched but can't find any. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post but, for those who came here looking for an answer, I found this plugin "Context Menu Toggle Comments", you can install it directly from the plugin section in visual studio code.
It adds at the bottom of the context menu:
"Toggle Block Comment"
"Toggle Line Comment"

Here is the link:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=henryclayton.context-menu-toggle-comments

Answer (score -1):

To comment/uncomment line, it is much simpler to press ctrl+/

Alternative : ctrl+k ctrl+c to comment, and ctrl+k ctrl+u to uncomment.

Btw, you can also comment multiple lines at once , just select a block of code you want to comment/uncomment and press hotkeys mentioned above.

Comment: And if you use `Ctrl+Shift+/` it will comment using block mode instead of line mode (`Command+Option+/` on Mac).

Comment: CTRL+/ doesn't seem to do anything for me. I wonder if there's something that has to be enabled in configuration? CTRL+SHIFT+/ does give me the block commenting though. And same to uncomment.